# How to scrape iframe using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

I want to extract all comment in a website. The website using iframe for the comment section. I already tried to scrape it using selenium. but unfortunaly, i just can scrape 1 comment. How to scrape the rest of the comment and archive it to csv or xmls?

- Code :

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    page = driver.get("https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5307853/ri-disebut-punya-risiko-korupsi-yang-tinggi?_ga=2.13736693.357978333.1608782559-293324864.1608782559")
    
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='xcomponent-component-frame xcomponent-visible']")))
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    
    xpath = '//*[@id="cmt66363941"]/div[1]/div[1]'
    extract_name = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    username=extract_name.text
    
    xpath = '//*[@id="cmt66363941"]/div[1]/div[2]'
    extract_comment = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    comment=extract_comment.text
    
    print(username, comment)
```

- Output

```
    King Akbarmachinery
    3 hari yang lalu selama korupsi tidak dihukum mati disanalah korupsi masih liar dan ada kalaupun dibuat hukum mati setidaknya bisa mengurangi angka korupsi itu
    Laporkan
    2BalasBagikan:
```

by the way, how to erase this line from the output ?

```
Laporkan
2BalasBagikan:
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generalize your paths in order to grab all the users and all comments at the same time. You can grab all the comments and all the users using `presence_of_all_elements_located`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
page = driver.get(
    "https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5307853/ri-disebut-punya-risiko-korupsi-yang-tinggi?_ga=2.13736693.357978333.1608782559-293324864.1608782559")

iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='xcomponent-component-frame xcomponent-visible']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

xpath_users = "//div[contains(@class, 'comment__cmt_dk_name___EGuzI ')]"
extract_names = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath_users)))

xpath_comments = "//div[contains(@class, 'comment__cmt_box_text')]"
extract_comments = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath_comments)))

for user, comment in zip(extract_names, extract_comments):
    user = user.text.split("\n")[0]
    comment = comment.text.split("\n")[0]
    print(user, comment)
```

Comment: actually, the comments in iframe have more than 1 page. because of this not all comments in the iframe are extracted. comments in the next page are not extracted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve the same using requests module issuing post requests with appropriate parameters which should fetch you the content across all the pages.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote

url = 'https://apicomment.detik.com/graphql'
payload = {"query":"query search($type: String!, $size: Int!,$anchor: Int!, $sort: String!, $adsLabelKanal: String, $adsEnv: String, $query: [ElasticSearchAggregation]) {\nsearch(type: $type, size: $size,page: $anchor, sort: $sort,adsLabelKanal: $adsLabelKanal, adsEnv: $adsEnv, query: $query){\npaging sorting counter counterparent profile hits {\nposisi hasAds results {\n id author content like prokontra  status news create_date pilihanredaksi refer liker { id } reporter { id status_report } child { id child parent author content like prokontra status create_date pilihanredaksi refer liker { id } reporter { id status_report } authorRefer } } } }}","variables":{"type":"comment","sort":"newest","size":10,"anchor":1,"query":[{"name":"news.artikel","terms":5307853},{"name":"news.site","terms":"dtk"}],"adsLabelKanal":"detik_finance","adsEnv":"desktop"}}

while True:
    r = requests.post(url,json=payload)
    container = r.json()['data']['search']['hits']['results']
    if not container:
        break
    else:
        for item in container:
            if not len(item['author']):continue
            print(item['author']['name'],unquote(item['content']))

    payload['variables']['anchor']+=1
```

Comment: This really big help for me. I'm never use requests module before, can i get some reference about it ? especially about web scrapping.